# Spring controller regex mapping

Tags: java, regex, spring

I have a url say `/prefix/part1/part2/.../partN/suffix` and in a controller i want to map anything between */prefix/* and */suffix* to one variable.

Approaches tried

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/prefix/{store:[\s\S]*}/suffix",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Also, tried regex : (.*), The interesting part is i don't know what N is. So, cant explicitly specify number of slashes possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I have an open JIRA issue requesting this ability](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12546), but the Spring core team apparently doesn't think that it's useful and is not interested in supporting it. You might make a note there.

In the meantime, the only option is to get the entire string from the request and parse it yourself.

Comment: That would be little painful. Because, between /prefix/ and /suffix if i have say "do-something" then behaviour should be different. I will make my comment in jira. Thanks.